# How to call two different actions in select tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to call two different java script functions in one select tag?
My code is next

```
<select id="selectMP" name="mjesto_potrosnje" onload="changePic()" onchange="changePic()">
    <optgroup label="Company1" id="0">
        <option onclick="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1')">
                Info 1
        </option>
        <option onclick="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','2')">
                Info 2
        </option>
        <option onclick="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','1')">
                Info 3
        </option>
        <option onclick="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','2')">
                Info 4
        </option>
        <option onclick="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','3')">
                Info 5
        </option>
        </optgroup>
</select>

//javascript functions below

<script>
function changePic(){
alert("changePic function");
}

function getData(a,b,c,d,e){
alert("getData function");
}
</script>
```

Only `changePic` function is called so i wonder why i happening that? And to make it even worse, on Mozilla and IE it works, but on Chrome not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach `onclick` to the options.

You can add multiple functions to the `onchange` function of the `select`. You can pass the`select` value to the function `getData`. The `.value` is the value of the attribute `value` of the `option`.

For example: for `<option value="1"> Info 1 </option>` the `this.value` will return 1 and so on.

And now, to the code:

```js
function changePic(){/* do what ever you want */}

function getData(a,b,c,d,e){
  console.log(a,b,c,d,e);
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = [a,b,c,d,e].join();
}
```

```html
<select id="selectMP" name="mjesto_potrosnje" onload="changePic()" onchange="changePic();getData.apply(null, this.value.split(/,/g))">
    <optgroup label="Company1" id="0">
        <option value="username@gmail.com,0,3210949,32109491,1">
                Info 1
        </option>
        <option value="username17@gmail.com,0,321023449,3dfg09491,2">
                Info 2
        </option>
        <option value="username14@gmail.com,0,32dfg949,3210234491,1">
                Info 3
        </option>
        <option value="username13@gmail.com,0,32xcv949,32xcv09491,1">
                Info 4
        </option>
        <option value="username12@gmail.com,0,3210949,32109491,1">
                Info 5
        </option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

<hr />

Output:
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Answer assumes that a,b,c,d are always the same.

Comment: This values are different for each option. In my case first three values are the same, but all 5 values can be different. So your answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: You are right.. I was updated my answer. No `eval` and clean as much as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This will first look at the value and if a value isn't set then it will take the html as shown in fiddle.

```
<select id="selectMP" name="mjesto_potrosnje" onload="changePic()" onchange="changeFunc()">
<optgroup label="Company1" id="0">
    <option>
            Info 1
    </option>
    <option value="test">
            Info 2
    </option>  
    <option>
            Info 3
    </option>
    <option>
            Info 4
    </option>
    <option>
            Info 5
    </option>
    </optgroup>
```

Javascript

```
function changePic(){
alert("changePic function");
}


function changeFunc() {
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectMP");
var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
alert(selectedValue);
```

}

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b1v44q1p/

Answer (score 2):

HTML

Keep option values as JSON object and handle them in onchange event

```
<select id="selectMP" name="mjesto_potrosnje" onchange="changePic()">
<optgroup label="Company1" id="0">
    <option value="{'username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1'}" onClick=x()>
            Info 1
    </option>
    <option value="{'username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1'}">
            Info 2
    </option>
    <option value="{'username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1'}">
            Info 3
    </option>
    <option value="{'username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1'}">
            Info 4
    </option>
    <option value="{'username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1'}">
            Info 5
    </option>
    </optgroup>
```

JavaScript

```
window.changePic = function() {
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectMP");
  var val = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(val);
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodhan/98k15zye/)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use eval to evaluate the options's value as a functional call. if you do this, take great care to ensure the `value` of the option is safe. as long as you can ensure that malicious code wont be inserted into this value, this usage of eval is safe:

**html**

```
<select id="selectMP" name="mjesto_potrosnje" onload="changePic()" onchange="changePic()">
    <optgroup label="Company1" id="0">
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1')">
                Info 1
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','2')">
                Info 2
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','1')">
                Info 3
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','2')">
                Info 4
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','3')">
                Info 5
        </option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

**code**

```
function changePic(){
    eval(document.getElementById('selectMP').value);
}

function getData(a,b,c,d,e){
    console.log(arguments);//as an example that it works.
}
```

```js
window.changePic = function(){
 eval(document.getElementById('selectMP').value);
};

window.getData = function(a,b,c,d,e){
 console.log(arguments);
};
```

```html
<select id="selectMP" name="mjesto_potrosnje" onload="changePic()" onchange="changePic()">
    <optgroup label="Company1" id="0">
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','1')">
                Info 1
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210949','32109491','2')">
                Info 2
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','1')">
                Info 3
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','2')">
                Info 4
        </option>
        <option value="getData('username@gmail.com','0','3210951','32109511','3')">
                Info 5
        </option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/ps0mt3ph/1/

**Final Thoughts**:

Eval is dangerous since it allows you to execute strings as code, so a better approach would be to store data attributes in the options, and then onchange you can lookup the selected option by value, retrieve the data attributes and then call your function. this is an exercise i leave to you, the reader as i feel like its a required learning step.